# Return results where a datetime value is between 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table like so and I'm trying to retrieve the result where '2021-06-02 09:30:00' would return id 272.

```
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | start_date          | end_date            |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| 271 | 2021-05-26 08:00:00 | 2021-05-26 09:00:00 |
| 272 | 2021-06-02 09:00:00 | 2021-06-02 10:00:00 |
| 273 | 2021-05-28 08:00:00 | 2021-05-28 09:00:00 |
| 274 | 2021-06-04 08:00:00 | 2021-06-04 09:00:00 |
| 275 | 2021-06-11 08:00:00 | 2021-06-11 09:00:00 |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BETWEEN

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`id` int, `start_date` varchar(19), `end_date` varchar(19))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`id`, `start_date`, `end_date`)
> VALUES
>     (271, '2021-05-26 08:00:00', '2021-05-26 09:00:00'),
>     (272, '2021-06-02 09:00:00', '2021-06-02 10:00:00'),
>     (273, '2021-05-28 08:00:00', '2021-05-28 09:00:00'),
>     (274, '2021-06-04 08:00:00', '2021-06-04 09:00:00'),
>     (275, '2021-06-11 08:00:00', '2021-06-11 09:00:00')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE '2021-06-02 09:30:00' BETWEEN `start_date` AND  `end_date`
> ```
>
> ```
> |  id |
> | --: |
> | 272 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4f75e01ad14239dccbe288ce68b729e)*